# How to determine the shape of this graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

This is for my physics class, we are learning about measurement and uncertainty and I can't wrap my head around this problem. If I am given the linear relationship:

[image]

How do I know what the shape of the graph of

[image] is?

Comment: Do a set of calculations for a range of values for I, K etc and plot... A spreadsheet works well...

Comment: This is not a linear relationship... At least not linear between $I$ and $x$. If it was, then the graph would be a simple, straight line. If you want to know the shape of the graph of $I$ vs $\frac1{x^2}$, then isolate $I$ and plot it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%5E2

Comment: I guess I was overthinking. If 1/sqr(I) plotted against x is a linear relationship, this has nothing to do with a graph of I vs 1/x^2. 1/x^2 is obviously non-linear.